# rails average between multiple models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational

I've been trying to get my head around doing things using my Rails relationships as opposed to pulling out large SQL joins, but I can't wrap my head around this one...

I have 3 models

Hotels
  Rooms
    Availables

They all have the appropriate has_many and belongs_to relationships.

What I want to do is on the overview page listing the Hotels of a particular City, i want to list the lowest price found for each hotel.

Now in SQL I would of course do the bit of code at the bottom, but in rails I could do something like this...

```
  def self.price
    Available.minimum(:price,
              :conditions => [ "price <> 0" ])
  end
```

This of course just pulls the lowest price of all of them, not a specific ID

The problem is the relationship Hotel.find(1234).rooms.availables

But I'd like to do something like this that could go inside my loop without having to reference the ID?

```
SELECT MIN(availables.price)

FROM availables

INNER JOIN rooms ON rooms.id = availables.room_id
INNER JOIN hotels ON hotels.id = rooms.hotel_id

WHERE hotels.id = 5077 and rooms.private = 0 and availables.price <> 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting up a has_many :through relationship on Hotel:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :availables, :through => :rooms

  # If you want "rooms"."private" condition, use these...
  has_many :public_rooms, :class_name => 'Room', :conditions => {:private => 0}
  has_many :public_availables, :through => :public_rooms, :source => :availables

  # This caches the value (potentially saving you db hits) for the
  # lifetime of the object, which you may or may not want depending
  # on your needs...
  def cheapest_available
    @cheapest_available ||= availables.minimum(:price, :conditions => ['availables.price > ?', 0])
  end
end
```

Now you can loop through all of the hotels in a particular city displaying the lowest price:

```
@city.hotels.each do |hotel|
  puts "#{hotel.name}: #{hotel.cheapest_available}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind!  The answer was right in front of me, i just didn't get the proper association.

```
  def self.price
    Available.minimum(:price,
              :conditions => [ "price <> 0" ])
  end
```

This works perfectly after using

```
:has_many, :through => :model
```

I just didn't realize I had to setup a more complex relationship in order for it to work properly...